# enhancing dynamic content in page with jQuery mobile causes site to freeze

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

So I'm trying to create a page (wit id 'sidebar') with dynamic content. The page acts like a sort of menu for whichever page you're on. That page will determine the content of the sidebar. The content is series of collapsible lists.

This technically works, but after navigating to one or two pages, the site freezes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is the relevant code. I send an ajax request to the server and it responds with the content. Then I remove the old content and add the new content. This code is run every time you click on a new page.

```
$.post('ajax.php',{page:currPage},function(data,status) {
    $('.ui-collapsible-set').children().remove();
    $(data).appendTo('.ui-collapsible-set');
    $('#sidebar').trigger('create'); 
});
```

This happens on both the simulator in chrome and on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after playing around a bit, I seem to have solved it. I had duplicated the same header and menu five times for each of my five pages. After making them external, the freezing stopped. Hopefully others find this useful